# VLC player does not remember last played position

Tags: macos, video, vlc, movie

I have been using MplayerX and recently thought of trying out VLC for watching movies. I noticed that the VLC player does not remember the last played position of the video. If I quit VLC and play the same video again, it plays it from the beginning.

Is this feature not provided by VLC? If not, is there any workaround to get this working?

Comment: If you want to DISABLE this damn annoying feature for audio files, go to `~/Library/Preferences/org.videolan.vlc/vlcrc` and set the line `macosx-continue-playback=2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current, stable releases of VLC don't offer this. However, you can go to the VLC nightly build site to download the latest version of VLC 3, with an updated Yosemite interface and H.265 support. Most importantly for you, though, they have added resume support.

From http://nightlies.videolan.org, you just have to click on Mac OS X Intel, and then click on "last" in the list.

VLC nightlies have no support from the VideoLAN team, so you have to be careful. However, in my experience, VLC 3.0 has been pretty stable.

Comment: Thanks! I just installed the nightly build and the continuing from last stopped position works great!

Comment: I have the same problem and I found this question by Google. I found that the VLC nightlies are no longer available. The remember last played position has been integrated in the stable version, Go to VLC > Preferences > Interface tab and just over half way down see Continue Playback > Set to Always.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin available called **VLC srpos** that will save and restore the playback position of the last played files. It is available [here](http://vlcsrposplugin.sourceforge.net/). There are numerous threads on this subject, I came across the plugin on the [VLC forum](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=101881), using a [well-known search engine](https://www.google.co.uk/) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm "kilometers" answer. To configure that option, you have to change to the "Advanced/All" settings, and then it is located in "Interface-->Main Interfaces-->QT-->Continue playback?"